# django url tag performance

Tags: django, performance

I was trying to integrate django-voting into my project following the [RedditStyleVoting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting) instruction.

In my urls.py, i did something like this:

```
    url(r'^sections/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$',
    vote_on_object,
    dict(
        model=Section,
        template_object_name='section',
        template_name='script/section_confirm_vote.html',
        allow_xmlhttprequest=True
        ),
    name="section_vote",
```

then, in my template:

```
    {% vote_by_user user on section as vote %}
{% score_for_object section as score %}

<form class="sectionvote" id="sectionup{{ section.id }}"{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %} action="{% url section_vote object_id=section.id, direction="clear" %}"{% else %} action="{% url section_vote object_id=section.id, direction="up" %}"{% endif %} method="POST">
<input type="image" id="sectionuparrow{{ section.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/aup{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png"></form>

{{ score.score|default:0 }}

<form class="sectionvote" id="sectiondown{{ section.id }}"{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %} action="{% url section_vote object_id=section.id, direction="clear" %}"{% else %} action="{% url section_vote object_id=section.id, direction="down" %}"{% endif %} method="POST"> 
<input type="image" id="sectiondownarrow{{ section.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/adown{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png"></form>
```

It takes over 1.3s to load the page, but by hard coding it like this:

```
<form class="sectionvote" id="sectionup{{ section.id }}"{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %} action="sections/{{section.id}}/clearvote/"{% else %} action="sections/{{section.id}}/clearvote/"{% endif %} method="POST">
```

```
<form class="sectionvote" id="sectiondown{{ section.id }}"{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %} action="sections/{{section.id}}/clearvote/"{% else %} action="sections/{{section.id}}/downvote/"{% endif %} method="POST">
```

I got 50ms. Just avoid the url tag resolving stuff I got a 20+ times performance improvement.
Is there something I did wrong? If not, then what's the best practice here, should we do things the `right` way or the fast way?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the development version, there has recently been a regression which has massively increased the time it takes to reverse-lookup URLs - see [the ticket here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13275). It is scheduled to be fixed before the final release of 1.2.

Comment: Should just add: that ticket has now been fixed, so if you svn up it should be faster.

Comment: Just did, same view, 32ms. One less bug to 1.2rc :)
Thanks again, Daniel.